# HTML5 & AccessKey

Tags: html

I've read: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-accesskey-attribute and it doesn't say anywhere if or how the 'Home' key on a keyboard can be used as an accesskey in HTML 5.

Does anybody know anything about this, or if it's at all even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't — only keys that enter characters can, and it is bad enough that you can [hijack normal keyboard shortcuts](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey#browserconflicts) with them with adding Home to the list of things that can be broken.

Comment: I was just going to use the Home key to let them go back to my Homepage. I don't see what's so bad about that. I understand that people (even me) don't like it when shortcuts are changed and I can't use them for my intended reasons, but I have not bought a single keyboard in the past 10 years where the Home key has actually been set to anything. So I thought, why not? *Anyway*, if it can't be used, then fair enough. :) And thanks for your answer. Link bookmarked.

Comment: The home button, by default, in every browser that I've tried it in, takes you to the top of the current page (good for getting to the nav bar) unless you at in an input (in which case it takes you back to the front of the input). Being sent to another page would be unexpected and unwelcome.

Comment: Agreed, WOW! As I was typing a reply, something very weird just happened. My Screen Resolution just changed by itself to something that looks like 800*600. Maybe it has something to do with Monitor drivers that Windows Update was installing.

Comment: That hijacking link is obsolete. Browsers have been reserving Alt+Shift+key for accesskeys for a long time.

Comment: FYI: [alt] + [home] usually takes you to your browser's home page